# How to give python command line arguments from command line mode

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I am attempting to start the python interpreter by typing `python` into my terminal. I also want to pass some command line arguments. If I try `python arg1` it things I am trying to open and run a script called `arg1`. So my question is, how can I pass command line arguments to python in the command line interpreter mode?

Comment: Read up on the `argparse` module, assuming you want to write your own program that takes command line arguments (it isn't clear that that is what you want to do).

Comment: It's not clear if you're having trouble trying to pass arguments to the python interpreter, to your script, or having trouble accessing them inside a script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already are.

Your `arg1` *is* a command line argument - to the python interpreter.

---

Maybe you're thinking of a **command line option**? (which really is just a specific type of command line argument)

Using the `-h` argument (`python -h`) will print all such options.

`python -Q new`, for example, will launch the interpreter with the new float division by default.

---

On the other hand, if you want to **pass command line arguments to your script**, you need to specify them *after* the script name: `python my_script.py arg1`

If you are on a UNIX based system, you can also use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) on your script, which will allow you to simply execute your script by name, skipping `python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#your script here
```

then run `./my_script.py arg1`

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to do it is by using the subprocess module and input variables.

An example would be:

```
 from subprocess import call
 x = raw_input('Which command line arguments? ')
 call(x, shell=True)
```

Try it with an `ls` command (`dir` for Windows users), it should work.

Comment: Your example is not passing any command line **arguments** - it's just executing a program without any. You'd have to use `call(x, shell=True)` to actually accept arguments from `raw_input`. I don't think the OP is trying to run another process, but it's not entirely clear

Comment: You are completely right. I had tested it only with IDLE. I already edited it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can access the command line arguments using sys.argv

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

% python scrpt.py a b c d

outputs: `['scrpt.py', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-` to mark the end of python's interpreter options:

```
python --interpreter-option-1 --interpreter-option-2 - --my-custom-option option-value my-custom-argument
```